# Laravel using Ajax with a View Composer

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a view composer that I'm using to calculate all the variables that go in the shopping basket (which is a partial that I include a lot) of the app I'm creating. It is essentially a much more complex version of this:

```
public function compose($view)
{
    $giftbox_total_pre = Giftbox::getTotal();
    $giftbox_items_total = number_format($giftbox_total_pre, 2);

    $view->with(compact(
        'giftbox_items_total',
    ));
}
```

Then in my routes I have:

```
View::composer(['layouts.bag', 'shop.basket', 'giftbox.basket'], 'Acme\Composers\BasketComposer');
```

But, I'm just adding Ajax to my app, and it would be good if after a request I could grab the variables from the View Composer. Is there a way of doing that? Or is the composer the wrong thing to be using in this instance?

For example, to add an item without Ajax, I have a controller function like the following route:

```
Route::post('/cart/add/{type?}/{quantity?}', 'CartsController@addToCart');
```

And controller:

```
public function addToCart($type='subscription', $quantity=1)
{
    $product = Product::find(Input::get('id'));
    $price = $product->box_price;

    Cart::insert([
        'id' => $type . $product->id,
        'table_id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->name,
        'price' => $price,
        'quantity' => $quantity,
        'cart_type' => $type,
    ]);

    return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Added to cart!');
}
```

First, proper, Laravel project so I may have myself in a bit of a mess! I can Ajax submit to the route and it works fine, but I just can't work out how to get back a decent JSON array of the cart.

Comment: So the response should be the whole cart plus `giftbox_items_total` like you have it in the view composer as JSON?

Comment: Yes, but how do I access variables made inside a view composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View composers are nice, but they are for views. And when you return JSON you don't use views but

```
return Response::json($data);
```

This means no view will be rendered. I you move all the logic from the composer inside a function on the model. (It looks like you sort of already that with `Giftbox::getTotal()`)

And then just call that method in the controller

```
$giftbox_items_total = Giftbox::getTotal();
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I got a little mixed up with my view composers. I've moved the whole function into the model like you said, then in my composer I just set up a `$cart = CartModel::get()` and then just carry on as before with `$view->with($cart);`. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
return Response::json(['html' => (string)View::make('cart.widget')]);
```